# Расположение полей класса в памяти

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Имеется вот такой класс:

```
template <typename Type>
class Vector
{
public:
    Type x, y, z;
};
```

Для удобства я добавил в него оперетор досутпа по индексу. Реализовал так:

```
template <typename Type>
class Vector
{
public:
    Type& operator[] (size_t index)
    {
        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: return x;
            case 1: return y;
            case 2: return z;
        }
        return z;
    }
public:
    Type x, y, z;
};
```

Получилось громоздко. Позже мне пришло в голову написать такую версию оперетора:

```
template <typename Type>
Type& Vector<Type>::operator[] (size_t index)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Type*>(this)[index];
}
```

Будет ли последняя версия опрератора на разных платформах работать одинаково?
При условии что:

1. Тип у всех полей класса одинаковый.
2. У всех полей одинаковый модификатор доступа.

Comment: Практически уверен, что гарантии расположения в памяти нет, у вас не POD-класс.

Comment: обычно для подобных целей используют `union` структуры и массива

Comment: @MaximTimakov: Мне кажется, union не лучшая идея, т. к. type punning — это UB.

Comment: @VladD а почему не POD? (если Type например int)

Comment: Во втором варианте, если `index` отличен от нуля, то происходит выход за пределы массива из одного элемента (`x` при арифметике указателей считается массивом из одного элемента), что приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Comment: Проще массив из трех элементов объявить и по честному выбирать по индексу (Type a[3]).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan: для Type = int может быть и POD, но у ТС нету такого ограничения

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет, гарантий таких нет и быть не может. Особенно если вдруг вы добавите в класс что-то виртуальное - это практически 100% гарантия, что адрес `this` и адрес первого поля будут разными.

Могут сыграть свою роль всякие выравнивания и тому подобные тонкости.

Но какой смысл обращаться к набору данных как к элементам массива, но при этом не сделать его массивом? Если животное на 4 лапах, лает, как собака, и кусается как собака - то это таки собака! Делайте массив.

Только в отличие от Stanislav Volodarskiy я бы - если вам дорого как память обращение через поля x, y, z - делал через ссылки:

```
template <typename Type>
class Vector {
public:
    Type& operator[](int i) { return data[i]; }
    const Type& operator[](int i) const { return data[i]; }
public:
    Type &x = data[0], &y = data[1], &z = data[2];

private:
    Type data[3];
};
```

Тогда обращение к данным ничем не отличается от вашего: https://ideone.com/W0y5M5

Comment: А почему собака, а не [утка](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)?

Comment: @VladD Не знаю, первое, что на ум пришло...

Comment: Ссылки очень гасят скорость конструктора и лишней памяти занимают очень много. Если-бы у них был класс размещения автоматический, то они бы автоматически вычислялись, но внутри класса : обязалово, чтобы они присутсвовали.

Comment: @AlexGlebe https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YGqoYfqP1 - ссылки ничего не добавляют, и даже короче, если без оптимизатора. А с оптимизатором разницы никакой... Да, если делать сложные типы, то, возможно, лучше инициализировать немного не так, но на суть — "*гасят скорость конструктора и лишней памяти занимают очень много*" — это не влияет: ни гашения скорости, ни перерасхода памяти не видно...

Comment: Лишняя память: `sizeof(Vector<int>)=40`  3*8 ссылки + 3*4 интов + 4 выравнивание = 40 байт. Лишняя работа в конструкторе : `mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] ;  mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx` *(`&x = data[0]`)*

Answer (score 7):

Если изменить интерфейс, можно обойтись без сомнительных приведений. Вы готовы писать `v.x() = 42;` ?

```
template <typename Type>
class Vector {
public:
    Type& operator[](int i) {
        return data[i];
    }
    Type& x() { return data[0]; }
    Type& y() { return data[1]; }
    Type& z() { return data[2]; }

private:
    Type data[3];
};
```